# TextView doesn`t center newly inserted text

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have one textView in ScrollView, and it doesnt center text after inserting. I tried change properties later,in code section, but it was useless. Maybe its all because of Anco.

TextView resultdop is the one I was asking about. Other TextView, resultfield, works fine.

**XML code:**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_below="@id/result">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultdop"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Code**

```
if (resultdop.text == ""){
                val city: String = userfield.text.toString()
                val key = "e9c95bab1d070877909fd3e55310c60c"
                val url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=$key&units=metric&lang=ru"
                val urls = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=$city&appid=$key&units=metric&lang=ru"
                //val imm: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
                //imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
                doAsync {
                    val apiresponse = URL(url).readText()
                    val weather = JSONObject(apiresponse).getJSONArray("weather")
                    val desc = weather.getJSONObject(0).getString("description")
                    val main = JSONObject(apiresponse).getJSONObject("main")
                    val temp = main.getString("temp")
                    resultfield.text = "Температура: $temp ℃, $desc"
                    val apiresponses = URL(urls).readText()
                    val list = JSONObject(apiresponses).getJSONArray("list")
                    var otvet = ""
                    for (i in 1 until list.length()){
                        val obj = list.getJSONObject(i)
                        val tempd = obj.getJSONObject("main").getInt("temp")
                        val weatherd = obj.getJSONArray("weather")
                        val descd = weatherd.getJSONObject(0).getString(("description"))
                        val time = obj.getString("dt_txt")
                        otvet += "$time \n $tempd ℃, $descd \n \n"
                    }
                    resultdop.text = otvet
                }
                resultdop.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                resultdop.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
                resultdop.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY
            }
```

Comment: `resultdop.text = otvet` needs to be on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:textAlignment="center"` from scroll view and linear layout. if the `textView layout_width` is `match_parent` then you can apply either `android:textAlignment="center"` or `android:gravity="center"` it will work.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/result"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultdop"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and Try Invalidate Cache/Restart Android studio